# JavaScript/jQuery - Navigation between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know which is the proper way to navigate between pages using ajax calls.

An example, we got this 3 html pages.

- users.html (with users.js which initializes it and has its own functions)
- cars.html (with cars.js which initializes it and has its own functions)
- bills.html (with bills.js which initializes it and has its own functions)

What would be the proper way to go from users.html to cars.html ? I got this problem because I dont know how to "load" the cars.js after doing the ajax call in users.html.

¿If I load it with $.getScript(), how can I remove the users.js after adding the cars.js?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there some particular reason you can't just navigate in the usual way?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I would like to add transitions/animations between the pages

Comment: Then Just add a fadeIn on document ready and a fadeOut on on navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to build a SPA (Single Page Application). You will have one index html file that uses the other html files as templates. For example you have a div main container whose content is replaced with users.html/cars.html/bills.html upon clicking a link.

Routing helps you get that done without refreshing the page. It also supports history.
Look up dependency injection so that you learn how you can download only the js files you depend on.

If you don't use routing and you only change the page content you lose history which is a really neat thing to have.

[SPA with Routing and Templating](https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating)
[Routing with Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/docs/routes)

Examples:

```
<body>
<a href="#/cars">Cars</a>
<a href="#/bills">Bills</a>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="sammy.js"></script>
<script>
    (function() {
        app.router = Sammy(function () {

            var selector = '#wrapper';

            this.get('#/cars', function() {
                $.get('cars.html', function (view) {
                    $(selector).html(view);
                });
            this.get('#/bills', function() {
                $.get('bills.html', function (view) {
                    $(selector).html(view);
                });                
            });

        });
        app.router.run('#/cars'); //Link to load on app opening
    }());
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call page with $.get() like

```
$.get( "cars.html", function( data ) {
  $(document).html(data);
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

In cars.js use all functions with $(document).ready()
but all functions must be:

```
$(document).on("yourevent","selector",function(){

});
```

while you load page cars.js will load if you import it in cars.html page
Read more about [jquery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and [jquery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)